# How do I generate Angular route configurations dynamically/pragmatically?

Tags: typescript, angular, angular2-routing

Hi I am trying to define the Angular 2 route paths pragmatically.

I have a service that returns the paths, **all the paths use a common component for routing**

the service is shown below, (all paths are generated dynamically)

```
export class PagesService{
    getPages() :string[] {
        return  [{"slug": 'john',"name": 'John'},{"slug": 'martin',"name": 'Martin'},{"slug": 'alex',"name": 'Alex'},{"slug": 'susan',"name": 'Susan'}]
    }
}
```

The routing component,

```
@Component({
    selector : 'app',
    template :  `
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    `,
    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
})
@RouteConfig([
    {path: '/', name: 'Home', component: HomeComponent}
])
export class RouteComponent{
    constructor(private _pageService: PagesService){
        this.pages = this._pageService.getPages()
    }
}
```

Is there any method like `*ngFor` that can be used to loop through `pages`  inside the `RouteConfig` decorator?

I want to get the route configurations as,

something like,

```
{path: '/{{page.slug}}', name: '{{page.name}}', component: PersonComponent}
```

thanks

Comment: See [Router#config](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/Router-class.html)

Comment: @EricMartinez that's the answer, would you care making an answer too? :)

Comment: @toskv done!!!! (needed the extras `!`...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As suggested by @toskv

You can accomplish this by using [Router#config](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/Router-class.html) which lets you to configure routes dynamically.

Super simple snippet using the service in your question

```js
@Component({
    // Generate de router links dynamically as well
    template : `
        <div  *ngFor="#page of pages">
            <a [routerLink]="[page.name]">
                {{page.slug}}
            </a>
        </div>
    `,
    providers : [PagesService]
})
export class App {
    pages = [];
    constructor(public pgSvc: PagesService, router: Router) {
        this.pages = pgSvc.getPages(); // cache the pages
        let config = []; // Array to contain the dynamic routes
        for(let i = 0; i < this.pages.length; i++) {
            config.push({
                path: this.pages[i].slug, 
                name : this.pages[i].name, 
                component: PersonComponent
            });
        }
        // Configure the Router with the dynamic routes
        router.config(config);
    }
}
```

Here's a [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/JXV2rSyk9hgw9M8qJ1Us?p=preview) with the example working

Comment: thank you for the answer, is there a specific reason for making `pgSvc` public?

Comment: @Marty just for convenience. You can make it private as well. By doing it in the constructor I avoid doing this `class App { pgSvc; constructor(pgSvc) { this.pgSvc = pgSvc} }`, if I do it in the constructor TS converts it for me.

Comment: in the plnkr example, it is given as: `<a [routerLink]="[page.name, {name : page.slug}]">` thus the data is passed to the component via the url query. (`?name=javascript`) is there a workaround to do it silently?

Comment: @Marty yes, in this [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/2Gnvw5vrGZ48vfQB623L?p=preview) I'm using RouteData instead of RouteParams.

Comment: This is exactly what I was thinking of. Thank you so much.