# Angular2: How do I achieve selectability of a specific route config list based on a external value

Tags: javascript, architecture, angular, angular2-routing

I am trying to use two different Route Configs in one .ts file which is of the same level of route and same parent path based on a service variable value.

The clause is, if a value of a external setting variable is true it will use one list of child routes and if its another then it will use second list. The route path and level is the same.

Eg:

Parent route `/parent...` (non terminal route) then in the child route config `if service.value is true` then it will use the following route config

```
@RouteConfig([
  {path: '/', component: ChildComponent, name: 'ChildCmp' },
  {path: '/test', component: SecComponent, name: 'SecCmp' },
  {path: '/tester', component: OptionalComponent, name: 'ThCmp' }
])
```

else if `service.value is false` it will use the following:

```
@RouteConfig([
  {path: '/', component: ChildComponent, name: 'ChildCmp' },
  {path: '/test', component: SecComponent, name: 'SecCmp' }
])
```

Is it possible to `inject` route config lists to the list or provide if statements based on `service.value`? Any ideas on how to achieve this modularity or selectability of route configs?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I generate Angular route configurations dynamically/pragmatically?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35991639/how-do-i-generate-angular-route-configurations-dynamically-pragmatically)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Router#config](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/Router-class.html) which will let you to configure routes dynamically.

So it's as simple as follows

```js
class Child {
  config = [];
  constructor(public svc: Service, router: Router) {
    if(svc.value == 1) {
      this.config = [
        {path: '/', component: ChildComponent, name: 'ChildCmp' },
        {path: '/test', component: SecComponent, name: 'SecCmp' },
        {path: '/tester', component: OptionalComponent, name: 'ThCmp' }];
    }
    else if(svc.value == 2) {
      this.config = [
        {path: '/', component: ChildComponent, name: 'ChildCmp' },
        {path: '/test', component: SecComponent, name: 'SecCmp' }
        ];
    }

    // Set the config
    router.config(this.config);
  }
}
```

Here's a [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/Ttzsp23DJlvzH2igxf3O?p=preview) with the example working. Toggle the value in the Service to see the values changing.

Comment: Does it mean that we can push config's dynamically. correct?

Comment: Exactly, see this other [question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35997976/4933038) (similar answer), and you may want to see this other [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36114571/4933038)